# How do i print specific parts of a users input based on another users input?

Tags: python

I'm confused on how I print a specific users input based on another input entered by a user. For example if I had a sample input of:

```
A A B B
1 3
```

I would want it to output A and B since A is the first element and B is the third.

How would I do this with a code like this:

```
user = input().split()
user1 = input()
print()#Don't know what to do from here
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
user = input().split()
user1 = input().split()
for i in range(len(user)):
    if str(i + 1) in user1:
        print(user[i])
```

Comment: @YxC if it solved your problem you can always accept this answer by clicking on the check mark

Answer (score 1):

Try using iteration to take values from `user1` and get the values of `user` with indexes from `user1`.

So something like so:

```
values = input().split(" ") #changed user to values for readability
indexes = input().split(" ") #changed user1 to indexes

print(" ".join([values[int(i)-1] for i in indexes if int(i) <= len(values)]))
```

This uses [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to simplify the iteration we need to use and `join` to convert the resultant list into a string.

Comment: This gives an error but I think I get what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Changed it now, just realised that I forgot to convert indexes to integers. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
user = input().split()
user1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in user1:
    print(user[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
> A A B B
> 1 3
```

I would assign the input values to lists, then use the numbers in the second list as indices

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_input = input('Input some letters: ')
    first_list = first_input.split(' ')
    
    second_input = input('Input some numbers: ')
    second_list = second_input.split(' ')
    for num in second_list:
        second_list[second_list.index(num)] = int(num)
        
    third_list = []
    for num in second_list:
        third_list.append(first_list[num])
        
    print(f'The letters are: {third_list}')
```

And the output would be:

```bash
> Input some letters: A A B B
> Input some numbers: 1 3
> The letters are: ['A', 'B']
```